# Converting a string to a Long (java) & Google's personID

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to get the logged in Google user's googleID.  I am able to get this value as a String object, however I want to be able to store it as a Long object (as in a long integer).

However, when I do this I am greeted with the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "123456789012345678901"
            at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
            at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:364)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
            at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:476)
```

The string that I am trying to convert is 21 characters long.  Why is it throwing this error?  What can I do to resolve it?

My code is below

```
   if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(m_gacGoogleApiClient) != null) {
       Person perGooglePerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(m_gacGoogleApiClient);

       String strGoogleID = perGooglePerson.getId();
       Long lonGoogleID = Long.valueOf(strGoogleID);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum `long` value is 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 = 9223372036854775807L. Your 21-digit number is way too large to fit in a `long`. To avoid the error, you can keep it as a `String` or you can use a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Thanks! WIll mark it as the answer in 7 minutes (as notified by S.O.)